# 403 forbidden error going through aws load balancer

Tags: security, load-balancing, http-status-code-403, amazon-web-services

I am running an IIS 7 Server behind an AWS load balancer.  I am using a Verisign SSL certificate which is installed properly but whenever I put in the URL, or the DNS name of the load balancer I get a 403 error:

`error 403 - forbidden: access is denied you do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied`

I can access it just fine from localhost, and if I just put the public IP address of the server in it works as well.  It just doesn't work through the load balancer.  It's like IIS blocks all traffic from it.

I've tried:

- Reinstalling the certificate - revoked it rekeyed it
- Recreating the load balancer with intermediate certs and without intermediate certs.

I got the intermediate certs from: https://knowledge.verisign.com/support/ssl-certificates-support/index?page=content&actp=CROSSLINK&id=AR1409&TID=retailssl

Using a GoDaddy certificate works great but my boss wants us to use verisign.

I followed the steps here to install the certs for the load balancer.

http://www.xdevsoftware.com/blog/post/Upload-IIS-SSL-Certificate-into-Amazon-Elastic-Load-Balancer.aspx

Is there a setting on IIS I can change to allow traffic in from my load balancer?

Thanks!

Comment: I found it started working once I updated the DNS entry to point to the loadbalancer.  I don't know why exactly, but it is working now.

Comment: Where was it pointing previously?

Answer (score 0):

Check your application pool account (or anonymous user) to see if it has permission to the certs folder...